# Sorting out and finding desired infos in A Dataframe: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
# Prompt user to input one of the district values
district_input = input("Enter one of the values from the second column: "
      "Semt    District\n"
      "Arnavutköy    Karlibayir Mh.\n"
      "Arnavutköy    Bolluca Mah.\n"
      "Arnavutköy    Hicret Mah.\n"
      "Arnavutköy    Tahtakale\n"
      "Arnavutköy    Deliklikaya\n"
      "Arnavutköy    Mavigol Mh.\n"
      "Arnavutköy    Hastane Mah.\n"
      "Arnavutköy    Ömerli Mh.\n"
      "Avcilar    Üniversite\n"
      "Avcilar    Denizköskler\n"
      "Avcilar    Firuzköy\n"
      "bagcilar    Göztepe\n"
      "Besiktas    Ulus\n"
      "Besiktas    Arnavutköy\n"
      "Besiktas    Kültür\n"
      "Besiktas    Kurucesme\n"
      "Besiktas    Mueyyitzade\n"
      "Besiktas    Nisbetiye\n"
      "Besiktas    Bebek\n"
      "Besiktas    Levazim\n"
      "Besiktas    Etiler\n"
      "Besiktas    Gayrettepe\n"
      "Besiktas    Ortaköy\n"
      "Besiktas    Mecidiye\n"
      "Besiktas    Konaklar\n"
      "Besiktas    Balmumcu\n"
      "Besiktas    Levent\n"
      "Besiktas    Visnezade\n"
      "Besiktas    Akatlar\n"
      "Besiktas    Türkali\n"
      "Besiktas    Muradiye\n"
      "Besiktas    Dikilitas\n"
      "Besiktas    Cihannüma\n"
      "Besiktas    Abbasaga\n"
      "Besiktas    Tomtom\n"
      "Besiktas    yildiz\n"
      "Besiktas    Sinanpasa\n"
      "beyoglu    Tomtom\n"
      "beyoglu    Haciahmet\n"
      "beyoglu    Hacimimi\n"
      "Ümraniye    istiklal Mh.\n"
      "Ümraniye    İstiklal Mh.\n"
                      )


# Check if the input district exists in the dictionary
if district_input in encoded_values_dict:
    encoded_values = encoded_values_dict[district_input]  # Get the encoded values for the input district
    district0, district1, district2 = encoded_values  # Unpack the encoded values into separate variables
    print(f"Encoded Values for {district_input}: district0={district0}, district1={district1}, district2={district2}")
else:
    print("Invalid district input. Please enter a valid district from the list.")




SquareMeter = int(input("Enter the square meter of the house: "))  # User input for square meter
BuildingAge=int(input("how old your building do you want to be?:enter a value from 0 to 38"))
Floor = int(input("In which floor do you want your apartment to be: "))
Number_of_Floors=int(input("number of floors in your apartment:"))
Elevator=int(input("do you want an apartment with elevator or without elevator:(with=1,without=0)"))
number_of_bathrooms=int(input("how many bathrooms do you want in your apartment:"))
Otopark=int(input("do you want with parking or without parking?(with= enter 1,without=enter 0)"))
steeped_alley=int(input("do you want steeped Alley?(yes= enter 1,no=enter 0)"))
material_used_and_luxuriness=int(input("please say how luxury your apartment should be,(1 for typical least luxury house untill 4 for the most luxury):"))
prestige_of_that_district_and_its_vicinity=int(input("how luxury do you want your vicinity to be?:(1 least luxury,2,3,4,5 the most luxury vicinities in istanbul)"))


print("for your desired values:",district_input,SquareMeter,BuildingAge,Floor,Number_of_Floors,Elevator,number_of_bathrooms,Otopark,steeped_alley,material_used_and_luxuriness,prestige_of_that_district_and_its_vicinity,"the predicted price would be:")
Price = lasso.intercept_ + lasso.coef_[0] * district0 + lasso.coef_[1] * district1 + lasso.coef_[2] * district2 + \
        lasso.coef_[3] * SquareMeter + lasso.coef_[4] * BuildingAge + \
        lasso.coef_[5] * Floor + lasso.coef_[6] * Number_of_Floors + \
        lasso.coef_[7] * Elevator + lasso.coef_[8] * number_of_bathrooms + \
        lasso.coef_[9] * Otopark + lasso.coef_[10] * steeped_alley + lasso.coef_[11] * material_used_and_luxuriness + lasso.coef_[12] * prestige_of_that_district_and_its_vicinity
print("Predicted Price:", Price)

def find_district_info(district, BuildingAge,SquareMeter,Floor,Number_of_Floors,Elevator,number_of_bathrooms,Otopark,steeped_alley,material_used_and_luxuriness,prestige_of_that_district_and_its_vicinity):
    district_info = transactions_master_df[(transactions_master_df['District'] == district) & 
                                           (transactions_master_df['Building Age'] == BuildingAge)&
                                           (transactions_master_df['SquareMeter'] == SquareMeter)&
                                           (transactions_master_df['Floor'] == Floor)&
                                           (transactions_master_df['Number of Floors'] == Number_of_Floors)&
                                           (transactions_master_df['Elevator'] == Elevator)&
                                           (transactions_master_df['number of bathrooms'] == number_of_bathrooms)&
                                           (transactions_master_df['Otopark'] == Otopark)&
                                           (transactions_master_df['steeped alley'] == steeped_alley)&
                                           (transactions_master_df['material used and luxuriness'] == material_used_and_luxuriness)&
                                           (transactions_master_df['material used and luxuriness'] == prestige_of_that_district_and_its_vicinity)
                                                                                                    ]
    
    if len(district_info) == 0:
        return "District not found"
    
    semt = district_info.iloc[0]['Semt']
    avg_price = district_info['Price'].mean()
    
    return semt, avg_price



semt, avg_price = find_district_info(district_input, BuildingAge, SquareMeter, Floor, Number_of_Floors, Elevator, number_of_bathrooms, Otopark, steeped_alley, material_used_and_luxuriness, prestige_of_that_district_and_its_vicinity)
print(f"For the district {district_input}:")
print(f"Semt: {semt}")
print(f"Average apartment price: {avg_price}")
```

As you can see here, I have received some parameters from the user for an apartment pricing data frame. Then I compare and sort out the desired parameters of the user. And when I finally want to print out those values in the line: `--> 290 semt, avg_price = find_district_info(district_input, BuildingAge, SquareMeter, Floor, Number_of_Floors, Elevator, number_of_bathrooms, Otopark, steeped_alley, material_used_and_luxuriness, prestige_of_that_district_and_its_vicinity)`, I get the following error. I saw similar questions in StackOverflow but they didn't help. they were saying you should change parenthesis to braces or for example, when you're trying to insert three elements from a list into two variables, this error will show up.

All these questions didn't help me solve this error, so I decided to post this. I appreciate any helpful advice.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\nimae\OneDrive\Desktop\Documents\Python\IstanbuL Housing_revised.py:290
    284     avg_price = district_info['Price'].mean()
    286     return semt, avg_price
--> 290 semt, avg_price = find_district_info(district_input, BuildingAge, SquareMeter, Floor, Number_of_Floors, Elevator, number_of_bathrooms, Otopark, steeped_alley, material_used_and_luxuriness, prestige_of_that_district_and_its_vicinity)
    291 print(f"For the district {district_input}:")
    292 print(f"Semt: {semt}")

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\nimae\OneDrive\Desktop\Documents\Python\IstanbuL Housing_revised.py:287
    284         avg_price = district_info['Price'].mean()
    285     return semt, avg_price
--> 287 result = find_district_info(district_input, BuildingAge, SquareMeter, Floor, Number_of_Floors, Elevator, number_of_bathrooms, Otopark, steeped_alley, material_used_and_luxuriness, prestige_of_that_district_and_its_vicinity)
    289 if result != "District not found":
    290     semt, avg_price = result

File c:\Users\nimae\OneDrive\Desktop\Documents\Python\IstanbuL Housing_revised.py:285
    283     semt = district_info.iloc[0]['Semt']
    284     avg_price = district_info['Price'].mean()
--> 285 return semt, avg_price

UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'semt' where it is not associated with a value
```

Comment: result = find_district_info(district_input, BuildingAge, SquareMeter, Floor, Number_of_Floors, Elevator, number_of_bathrooms, Otopark, steeped_alley, material_used_and_luxuriness, prestige_of_that_district_and_its_vicinity)

if result != "District not found":
    semt, avg_price = result
    print(f"Semt: {semt}")
    print(f"Average price: {avg_price}")
else:
    print("District not found") I realized that assigning find_district_info to a single variable solves the problem!

Comment: Replace `return "District not found"` with something more suitable. E.g `raise(ValueError("District not found"))`, or `return [None, None]`, etc. Otherwise you unpack the `"District not found"` string into letters with `semt, avg_price = ...`

Comment: After raising an error, I want the first input to show up and ask the user to input a correct value for the district.